# Use template to generate Word document

Tags: .net, vb.net, openxml

I have a Word Document stored on a server I wish to use as a template. I need to replace certain text with data from a database.

The two issues I have are: 
No office on the server to use Microsoft.Office.Interop, and I cannot save any documents to the server.

I think I am on the right track, but cannot come up with a viable solution. I am thinking my best route is to read into memory and use a byte array to allow the user to save the file.

I was doing something like this, but am currently stumped.

```
Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath & "Letters\Test.docx"
        Dim docBA As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(path)

        Dim wordDoc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, True)
        Using (wordDoc)
            Dim docText As String = Nothing
            Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream)

            Using (sr)
                docText = sr.ReadToEnd
            End Using

            Dim regexText As Regex = New Regex("FIRST_NAME")
            docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "TESTING!!!")

            Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create))
            Dim modBA As Byte()
            Using (sw)
                sw.Write(docText)
                modBA = sw.Encoding.GetBytes(sw.BaseStream, 0, sw.BaseStream.Length)
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= DownloadSample.docx")
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octectstream"
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(modBA)
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
            End Using
```

Comment: I tried doing this once and gave up.  Since a .docx is fundamentally an XML document, you could conceivably do an XSLT (I had some success but was way too cumbersome to be useful.)  You *could* have Office on the server, but it's not thread safe so you're asking for trouble there too.  My ultimate solution was to convert the Word document into a fillable PDF, write the user's web data to an FDF on Post and use PDFTk on the backend to merge the two at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, working with the Open XML file format, rather than attempting to edit a document in the Word application in a server environment.

One prolem you're going to have, however, is that you won't reliably be able to read the content as your sample code does and use RegEx. The reason is that, in the underlying Word Open XML text runs can (usually are) broken up by direct formatting commands, spelling errors, language formatting, and a myriad of other things.

Since the purpose of your choice of RegEx is to write data to "placeholders" the better approach is to use Content Controls (std elements) as the "targets". These can be located directly and data written to them. Content controls can even be bound to nodes in a Custom XML Part embedded in the document so that you can edit that XML file, rather than the Word document. There are examples for this on MSDN as well as discussions in MSDN and other forums.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested you can employ Open XML SDK to parse a document and modify it by creating your own find/replace engine that works on top of Open XML SDK. You should also consider using tags (Content Controls, Merge Fields, Bookmarks) to mark dynamic parts and create search logic that will search for these tags instead of text. I would say that Content Controls are the best option since they are the easiest to parse and provide the best user experience when designing template documents. Still if your budget allows, take a look at this [commercial .NET library](http://www.docentric.com/) which already does exactly what you need (and probably much more).